# Typescript optional generic with extends

Tags: typescript, generics, option-type, extends

I would like to write generic that is optional (the D in example below) and extends an interface. I can't figure out the syntax.

```
interface IUpdateItems {
   _id: string;
}

export const deleteItem = <T extends IUpdateItems, D = void extends IUpdateItems >(
   items: T[],
   itemToDelete: T | D
): T[] => {
   return items.filter((item) => item._id !== itemToDelete._id);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would look like this:

```
export const deleteItem = <T extends IUpdateItems, D extends IUpdateItems = never>(
   items: T[],
   itemToDelete: T | D
): T[] => {
   return items.filter((item) => item._id !== itemToDelete._id);
};
```

You should also replace `void` with `never` since `void` is not assignable to `IUpdateItems` causing an error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUAOATOlWQC2AzsgN4BQy1A%20sNgFzLFhSgDmA3BQL4UUQAHpgD2UMMgQiQLZNggAbCPiLIAvMgA8AFWRDIIbKQw48EAhBIAaZABE9gg0bRZcKy6Q0gIAN2gA%20AAoqamAiYiZtAG0AXSsQ5DDLbRFbRWUISOQAHzsKAEpI2PV-cgSoZQBXKBBE8IA6GGAFSChAwKTCfJK6y3q6bGQAQjUNTpS0pUh%20%20nzuHk4gA)